# Why is history.pushState() breaking my navigation functionality?

Tags: javascript, html, pushstate

I'm using `history.pushState()` to show a URL that indicates the dynamic content (an article) currently displayed.

If I return to my home page (index.html) after looking at some dynamic content and then try to visit another page other than index.html, my nav links become broken.

On mysite.com/articles whenever a new article is chosen I call `history.pushState(null, null, '/articles/' + <articleID>);`. This works correctly as I'd expect. The displayed URL becomes mysite.com/articles/articleID.

**Current Behavior:**

At this point, if I click a nav link to go back to `index.html` the page successfully changes to index.html but the displayed URL becomes mysite.com/articles/index.html

**Expected Behavior**

The displayed URL should become mysite.com or mysite.com/index.

So is my problem:

1. The way I'm using `history.pushState();` or
2. The way that my navigation links are configured?

Comment: You should redirect to the homepage using `/`, not `'/articles/' + <articleID>`

Comment: This was exactly my problem, thank you! If you'd like to resubmit this as an answer I can mark it as correct. For those experiencing the same issue, set your links like this `href="/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generic redirect method redirects everything to `/articles/<articleID>` including the link to home page (as you mention `...articles/index.html`).

While your app from a reason can resolve `articles/index.html` to home page (I'm not sure why). From now on, all the relative link (which not start with `/`) will be relative to the current path - `/articles/index.html`.

In order to fix this, you should exclude the homepage links from the generic redirect mechanizm and redirect to `/`.